# How to get an addres of AF_INET6 socket with recvfrom

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, ip-address

`recvfrom` requires the 5-th parameter to be a pointer to `sockaddr` structure and the 6-th parameter to be a pointer to a `socklen_t`.

`man recvfrom (3)` says:

> If the actual length of the address is greater than the length of the
>   supplied sockaddr structure, the stored address shall be truncated.

I don't get it how can I retrieve an address of a sending socket with AF_INET6 address family since the size of `sockaddr_in6` is greater than `sockaddr` thus it would be truncated by `recvfrom`.

Do I get it right that `recvfrom` can not retrieve addresses larger than `sizeof(sockaddr)`?

Do I get it right that even if I define an instance of `sockaddr_in6` cast it's address to `sockaddr*` and pass it to `recvfrom`, the function would not be able to know that enough space is available to store the address?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You pass the pointer of the `sockaddr_in6` (type-casted) and the size of the `sockaddr_in6` structure as arguments:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 in6;
socklen_t len6 = sizeof(in6);

recvfrom(sock, buf, buflen, (struct sockaddr *) &in6, &len6);
```

Since you pass in the correct length to the function, it will work.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I used to think that the last parameter is provided to `recvfrom` so that the function fills it with the actual sender address. Am I mistaking? Or the last parameter serves both purpose: before call to `recvfrom` to indicate available address buffer size and after call to store actual address size?

Comment: @Kolyunya It's used for both. When you call the function you tell it how big the socket address structure is, and when it returns the function have set it to the size it used to fill in the structure.

Answer (score 8):

It's correct to cast it to `sockaddr*` .

Further more, people use often `sockaddr_storage`, because it is [defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/basedefs/sys/socket.h.html) as

> The  header shall define the sockaddr_storage structure.
>   This structure shall be:
>
> - Large enough to accommodate all supported protocol-specific address structures
> - Aligned at an appropriate boundary so that pointers to it can be cast as pointers to protocol-specific address structures and used to
>     access the fields of those structures without alignment problems

In this way you can use it for several protocols, so you're not boundedn to only IPv6 or IPv4.

So you can do

```
struct sockaddr_storage addr;
socklen_t sa_len = sizeof(addr);

recvfrom (sock, buffer, sizeof (buffer), (struct sockaddr*) &addr, &sa_len);
```

If you need to know what kinf of sockaddr is, you can check the mandatory `sa_family_t   ss_family` field present in each sockaddr struct.

You may also be interested in this [link](http://www.kame.net/newsletter/19980604/) or this [one](http://long.ccaba.upc.es/long/045Guidelines/eva/ipv6.html).

Comment: Thank you for a `sockaddr_storage` reference, this really helped

Comment: Do you have negative experience or reference about **not** using `sockaddr_storage`? I'm asking because you mentioned it, and I've been avoiding it like the devil ever since for the sole reason that on some platforms it's a structure of sheer forbidding size. `sockaddr_in6` so far has always worked for me, but what does "has always worked for me" really mean...

Comment: well, as far as I know, that's a good practice for handling multi protocol cases. The standard does not mandate anything about the sizes of all the sockaddr structs (aligning for optimization is not forbidden, even though it's different from what's running on the wire), the only thing it is stated it that sockadrr_storage MUST be large enough to hold any of them.